# How to Convert two dimensional bson array into single in mongoDB C#?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

My document structure is

```
{
 " _id" : "",

 "Tickets" : [{
...

}]

}
```

I am fetching one item from Tickets in that collection, after fetching it is like

```
[[2002,1000],[10002, 100]]
```

With these values i need to fetch from another collection using in operator.
Problem is its two dimensional array.So i need to break it into one.

For that i am doing it manually like this

```
 public static BsonArray CombineArray(this IEnumerable<BsonValue> IEnumBv)
        {
            BsonArray returnArray = new BsonArray();

            IEnumBv.ToList().ForEach(o =>
                {
                    if (o.BsonType == BsonType.Array)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in o.AsBsonArray)
                        {
                            returnArray.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        returnArray.Add(o);
                    }
                }
                );

            return new BsonArray(returnArray.Distinct());
        }
```

Is it fine ? Or any best way is there to overcome these ?

I am using mongoDB,C#, C# native driver for mongoDb..
Thanks in advance..